# Javascript Syntax Puzzlement

Tags: javascript

I've ran this piece of code, I'm not sure how it is getting evaluated and produces it's results. I really like the way it does it and means I can run with the second code block.

```
function pathInfo(url) {
    var self = this;
    self.hasExt = url.indexOf(".") > -1 && url.substring(url.indexOf(".") + 1, url.length);
    self.ext = self.hasExt ? url.substring(url.indexOf(".") + 1, url.length) : undefined;
}

console.log(new pathInfo("/hello.html"));
```

This evaluates in the Chrome console as:

```
pathInfo { hasExt: "html", ext: "html" }
```

I was expecting:

```
pathInfo { hasExt: true, ext: "html" }
```

I do like the way it works but is it solid? If so I could just do this:

```
function pathInfo(url) {
    this.ext = url.indexOf(".") > -1 && url.substring(url.indexOf(".") + 1, url.length);
}
```

Comment: So what, exactly, is your question?

Comment: an explanation as to exactly what this code is doing? @MikeW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`&&` (logical AND) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in JavaScript will evaluate the left side first, and if it can be converted to `true` (i.e. is truthy), will then evaluate and return the right side.

The official documentation provides some illustrative examples:

```
a1 = true && true       // t && t returns true
a2 = true && false      // t && f returns false
a3 = false && true      // f && t returns false
a4 = false && (3 == 4)  // f && f returns false
a5 = "Cat" && "Dog"     // t && t returns Dog
a6 = false && "Cat"     // f && t returns false
a7 = "Cat" && false     // t && f returns false
```

Comment: So it actually evaluates the expression and returns it's value, i thought it would just return a boolean if there was actually a value to the substring

Comment: @No1_Melman To do that, you'd actually need to test: `(url.indexOf(".") + 1 < url.length)`

Comment: @No1_Melman Judging from your post history, it appears you're more familiar with C#. One important difference between JS and C# is that JS is *much* more loosely typed, which means JS expressions do not have to accept or return fixed types. This is what allows this kind of 'shorthand control structure' in JS that most other languages lack (though many would think that's a good thing).

Comment: Yeah i do :) , I do like javascript for this very reason :)

Comment: Javascript is like Lisp in this regard; this idiom has been used in Lisp for decades.

Answer (score 2):

An expression of the form:

```
expr1 && expr2 && expr3 ... && exprN && exprLast
```

is evaluated as follows: It evaluates each `exprI` from left to right; if it's falsy, the value of that subexpression is immediately returned as the value of the entire expression. If all `exprI` are truthy, it evaluates `exprLast` and returns its value.

Answer (score 1):

`hasExt` contains false if `url.indexOf(".") > -1` is evaluated as false, `url.substring(url.indexOf(".") + 1, url.length)` otherwise.

That's the sense of the `&&` operator in this case.

but `hasExt` will still evaluate as true if you test against it, since it is a none empty string.

What would make more sense for the definition of `ext` would be

```
ext = self.hasExt || undefined;
```

or

```
ext = self.hasExt ? self.hasExt : undefined;
```

which is the same thing.